# Fill in missing values of Df outer merged on 2 columns with values from _leftonly or _rightonly

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes that have overlapping data. In some instances of the outer merge, I have 1 DF with values that I'd like to populate for both DFs. They will always inner merge off of at least 1 value but the outer join will occur for the 2nd column in some scenarios.

```
As an Example:
ID_1  Name_1   ID_2   Name_2
1      Bob      NaN    NaN
```

In the above example I would like to take Bob from Name_1 and copy it over to Name_2

The best solution I have thought of is to separate them out of the outer join keying off of the indicator value, formatting them they way I want, and then concatenating them back together.

Is there a way to do this in 1 attempt? In reading some of the pandas documentation it appears that some type of a df.where() statement might work?

Comment: can you post some sample data and expected output? else we will just be guessing

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly your question what you are looking for is `df.mask`

```
>>> df.Name_2.mask(df.Name_2 == "NaN", df.Name_1, inplace=True)
1 Bob 
Name: Name_2, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi, this close to what I am trying to do. However, in your example, it is not scale-able. If I were to apply this to my full dataframe, it would make all of the missing rows equal to the same value (not replicating what is in the subsequent row)

Comment: I have been testing this, but it doesn't seem to edit it in place. I'm also not sure if the performance is that much better than just doing it separate...                        
    for i in range(0,len(df)):
        if df.iloc[i,1] == "NaN":
            df.iloc[i,1]=df.iloc[i,6]

Comment: Hi, if you want to do it in place you can just add the option (edited). Performance-wise, based on my experience using pandas methods is always better then your own methods (especially when you use .iloc). You could do some benchmarking if you want, this is my intuition.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have gotten it, any thoughts on this?

```
df['SEC_NAME_x'].fillna(df['SEC_NAME_y'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: I think is equivalent of using df.mask, they are both good solutions in accord with pandas best practices